# Xml element which contains html data when transforming xml to html using xsl and java styles are disappearing

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am facing an issue with the transform method on public abstract class Transformer.

I need to generate e-mails in Java, so i am using the above tranformer class and converting XML to HTML using XSL but one of the XML elements contains HTML code like below:

```
<data>
   <message>
  <font color="red">This is font color</font><br></br>
  <p>this is paragraph</p>
</message>
</data>
```

The XSL I used is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<html>
  <body>

<xsl:template match="/">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="/data/message"/></td>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Now the email font color red is not appearing and the br tag is also not working, but some data is appearing from the same line.

Can someone help me with this please.

Comment: Sorry all html styles are disappearing.

Comment: Can you correct the XSLT in your question as it is not well-formed. If you were using that XSLT exactly you would have got an error! The closing `</xsl:stylesheet>` needs to be at the end. Also the `html` should be inside the `xsl:template` as it is not valid to be a child of `xsl:stylesheet`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:value-of` only outputs the text value of a node, and will not copied any descendant elements like `br` or `font`. You could be using `xsl:copy-of` here, which will copy them.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:copy-of select="/data/message/node()"/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```